# updating the robots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, robots.txt

Ok so I want to add this

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

to the robots.txt in all the enviroments other then production...any idea on the best want to do this. Should i remove it from the public folder and create a routes/views

I am using rails 3.0.14 prior to asset pipeline...any suggestions

Comment: I'd make a capistrano task that uploads robots.txt during deploy.

Comment: Do you have an example of an after:deploy task ....would it be best to create the file on the fly or move the file ...suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a real working code from my project (it's a nginx config, not robots.txt, but idea should be clear).

```
task :nginx_config do
  conf = <<-CONF
   server {
      listen 80;
      client_max_body_size 2M; 
      server_name #{domain_name};

      -- snip --
    }
  CONF

  put conf, "/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{application}_#{rails_env}"
end
```

So, basically, you create content of your file in a string and then do `put` to desired path. This will make capistrano upload the content through SFTP.

Answer (score 4):

### Capistrano task for uploading a blocking robots.txt

I wrote this up again today, same path as Sergio's answer essentially, but sharing robots-specific result might save someone time :)

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Uploads a robots.txt that mandates the site as off-limits to crawlers"
  task :block_robots, :roles => :app do
    content = [
      '# This is a staging site. Do not index.',
      'User-agent: *',
      'Disallow: /'
    ].join($/)

    logger.info "Uploading blocking robots.txt"
    put content, "#{current_path}/public/robots.txt"
  end
end
```

Then trigger it from your staging recipe with something like

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:block_robots"
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I had to change current_path to release_path for some reason, though.